# Getting rows values into column where column values start with integer in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my SQL Server table structure with sample data:

```
DateValue            Status     EmpId
----------------------------------------
2018-05-28 8:00        01       2000347
2018-05-28 20:18       02       2000347
2018-05-28 8:00        01       2000348
2018-05-28 17:18       02       2000348
```

I want output like this:

```
sEmpId    Status (1) IN Time           Status (2) Out Time
---------------------------------------------------------------
2000347   2018-05-28 08:00:00.000      2018-05-28 20:18:00.000
2000348   2018-05-28 08:00:00.000      2018-05-28 17:18:00.000
```

You can find my try here - [**Row To Column**](https://rextester.com/JFP40613)

I am getting the following error

> Error(s), warning(s):
>   Incorrect syntax near '01'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally identifier cannot start with digit. You need to wrap columns with `[]`

```
select sEmpId, [01], [02]
from
(
  select sEmpId,dDateTime,sStatus
  from #temp
) d
pivot
(
  max(dDateTime)
  for sStatus in ([01], [02])
) piv;
```

**[rextester demo](https://rextester.com/DLLD8833)**

Answer (score 2):

```
Select 
   sEmpId,
   Max(Case When sStatus = '01' Then dDateTime End) As [In],
   Max(Case When sStatus = '02' Then dDateTime End) As [Out]
From #temp
Group By sEmpId
```

Comment: This wouldn't be accurate. They need the most recent `[In]` time, not the oldest.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use below query if in time and out time is in the same day:

```
select sEmpId,
       min(dDateTime) InTime,
       max(dDateTime) OutTime
from #temp
group by sEmpId, day(dDateTime)
```